# Joining a Team Breaks the "Privileges" Link in the Achievements Dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, achievements-dialog

After joining a team recently, I've found that on Stack Overflow the "Privileges" link in the achievements dialog is broken.  It now takes me [to the teams privileges page](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042869#privileges) instead of to the [SO privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).  On all other sites this still works as intended (including SO Meta).

The "Badges" link still works in SO but, interestingly, the opposite is true on the Teams page.  There, "Privileges" takes me to the above team privileges page while badges takes me to my normal SO badges page (despite the fact that I appear to have independent badges for the team).